# Hook_enable vs hook_install [granting permissions to user role]

Tags: 7, hooks

In Drupal 7, I'm trying to grant a permission to a user role using hook_install and it doesn't work. But it works with hook_enable. Do you know how to make it work with hook_install as well?

```
function porta_batch_editor_install() {
  $permissions = array('access porta batch editor');
  //grant 'access porta batch editor' permission to pb role
  foreach(array('pb role') as $role_name) {
    $role = user_role_load_by_name($role_name);
    user_role_grant_permissions($role->rid, $permissions); 
  }
}
```

It works with the following approach:

```
function porta_batch_editor_enable() {
  $permissions = array('access porta batch editor');
  //grant 'access porta batch editor' permission to pb role
  foreach(array('pb role') as $role_name) {
    $role = user_role_load_by_name($role_name);
    user_role_grant_permissions($role->rid, $permissions); 
  }
}
```

Comment: I believe it didnt work with hook_install because I was disabling and re-enabling the module, when I uninstalled and enabled it, it worked(on my dev site). So, afaik, re-enabling a module doesnt trigger hook_install.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should work on install. Are you actually uninstalling the module? Disabling and uninstalling is not the same thing in Drupal 7. Uninstall at `admin/modules/uninstall`, once the module is disabled. You can use `drush pm-disable/pm-uninstall module_name`.

- test.module

  ```
  function test_permission() {
    return array(
      'test permission' => array(
        'title' => t('Test permission title'),
      ),
    );
  }
  ```
- test.install

  ```
  function test_install() {
    $test_perm = array('test permission');

    $perms = module_invoke_all('permission');
    // We can find the 'test permission' in $perms.

    $role = user_role_load_by_name('administrator');
    user_role_grant_permissions($role->rid, $test_perm);
  }
  ```

The above gives administrators the test permission on module install.